# Google cloud key management - Redundant storage of keys

Tags: security, google-cloud-platform, redundancy, key-management, google-cloud-kms

Is there any automatic replication of CryptoKey in different locations. If not, can I create myself replications by creating multiple KeyRings in different locations ? Will Google Cloud services support this kind of manual replication ?

I could't find the answer in the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Key material is backed up for redundancy in multiple locations in case of failover, and provides an SLA on availability of this material: https://cloud.google.com/kms/sla

You cannot currently duplicate the same key in multiple regions, with the same key material.